# Confusion in calling touch event

Tags: iphone

I am using UISwipeGestureRecognizer for left and right direction swipe in my main view as follow:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer1,*recognizer;

    recognizer1 = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFromleft:)];
    [recognizer1 setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer1];
    [recognizer1 release]; 

    recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFromright:)];
    [recognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    [recognizer release];
```

and in this same view I am also using touch event like touch begin,move and end.

Both are used for different purpose.

My problem is that when I touch my view and moving it from left to right or right to left; 
UISwipeGestureRecognizer is called in between the touch began and touch moved method which i dont want

so anyone know how can i avoid this type of thing?
how can i tell the view that i am now want to use touch event or i am using UISwipeGestureRecognition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIGestureRecognizer/cancelsTouchesInView) there is a property called `cancelsTouchesInView`. So the way I see it is to determine if you want to handle the gesture or standard touch in swipeHandlers, and set the  `cancelsTouchesInView` property accordingly